# Show a field for filter in grid.php from other custom table in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, grid-layout

I need to show a column in grid.php file of my module, and that field having data from custom table that is created separately but that table also contain the entity id of the module so they are related.

I also want to provide the filter functionality for this field so if user type anything in that field the custom table search the entity id of the module's row and return the result accordingly.

Comment: you need to join collection from those 2 seprate tables using query.

Comment: You can use renderer
please check this link:
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use renderer for that.
Renderer allows you to get related data by foreign key,
You can load data by filtering your model.
Here is the guide how to setup renderer which gets custom data to your grid.

http://www.mydons.com/how-to-create-custom-column-renderer-in-magento-grid